# Uniform Convergence using Dirichlet's Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Suppose $f'$: (-1,1) → **R** and is bounded where $f(0) = 0$. Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)$$ converges uniformly on (-1,1) and $S'(0)=f'(0)$.

I believe I have to use Dirichlet's Test for Uniform Convergence (because $\frac{1}{n}$ is decreasing to $0$ and converges uniformly), but I do not know how to show $\sum f\left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)$ is bounded.

Edit: using the link; I used the Weierstrass M-test to show uniform convergence as it made the most sense, but now I am struggling with showing $S'(0)=f'(0)$. I would assume you would do term by term differentiation to get $$ S'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}f'\left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)$$ and then it would suffice to show that $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = 1$, which is where I get stuck.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468904/question-on-uniform-convergence-of-a-sum

Comment: It doesn't need to be bounded: before doing abstract manipulations, take an example. The most natural being $f(x)=x$. The MVT-based argument given by hamam_Abdallah is the most natural in y opinion (you *need* to use the assumptions on $f'$, after all).

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

For $x\in(-1,1)$, use MVT to get

$$f(\frac{x}{n+1})-f(0)=\frac{x}{n+1}f'(C_x)$$

and

$$|f(\frac{x}{n+1})|<\frac{M}{n}$$